# JqGrid Column Image data not show

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Here is my colNames:

colNames: ['', 'NTPEP Number', 'Manufacturer', 'Product', 'Status', 'Data', 'Actions'],

Here is my colModel:

```
colModel: [{ name: 'tc_id', index: 'tc_id', align: 'left', hidden: true, resizable: false, key: true },
                   { name: 'NTPEP_Number', index: 'NTPEP_Number', width: 150, align: 'left', resizable: false, formatter: fontColorFormat },
                   { name: 'Manufacturer', index: 'Manufacturer', width: 200, align: 'left', resizable: false },
                   { name: 'Product', index: 'Product', width: 100, align: 'left', resizable: false, formatter: fontColorFormat },
                   { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 150, align: 'left', resizable: false },
                   { name: 'Data', sortable: false, edittype: 'select', width: 100, align: 'left', sortable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return "<div id= action_" + rowObject[0] + " class='action'><div class='btn-group' id='actions'><div class='collapse navbar-collapse'><ul class='actions'><li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle grid-icon' data-toggle='dropdown'></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'><li><a href='#'>Product</a></li><li><a href='#'>Test</a></li></ul></li></ul></div></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"; }, resizable: false },
                   { name: 'Actions', index:'Actions',sortable: false, edittype: 'select', width: 95, align: 'left', sortable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return "<div id= action_" + rowObject[0] + " class='action'><div class='btn-group' id='actions'><div class='collapse navbar-collapse'><ul class='actions'><li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle grid-icon' data-toggle='dropdown'></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'><li><a href='#'>Product</a></li><li><a href='#'>Test</a></li></ul></li></ul></div></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"; }, resizable: false }],

        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [2, 10, 20, 50],   // page size dropdown
        pager: jQuery('#pager_Alerts'),
        pgbuttons: true,            // disable page control like next, back buttonssss
        viewrecords: true,          // disable current view record text like 'View 1-10 of 100' 
        pagerpos: 'right',
        recordpos: 'left',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        sortorder: "asc",
        sortname: "tc_id",
        loadtext: "Loading",
        width: 795,
        //multiselect: true,
        hoverrows: false,
        gridComplete: function () {

            $(".action").hide();

            $('.jqgrow').mouseover(function (e) {
                //debugger;
                var rowId = $(this).attr('id');

                //$(".action").hide();
                $("#action_" + rowId).show();
              //alert("You rolled over " + rowId);

            }).mouseleave(function () { $(".action").hide(); });;



        }
```

Here is my output:

[image]

on mouseover my Data column show image but Action column not.Tell me what i am doing wrong??

Comment: on changing div id's i got my desired result.